# How to compute cells using DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have 3 column Qty,Price and Amount and i need to compute the amount per line using DataGridView, what are the possible events I may use?

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Answer (score 1):

i assumed that Quantity is `Cell 0`, Price is `Cell 1`, and Amount is `Cell 2`

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
    Dim xQty as Double = CDBL(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value)
    Dim xPrc as Double = CDBL(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
    DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = xQty * xPrc
Next
```